# Como add um widget ao cabeçalho de um QTableWidget?

Tags: python

Olá, Quero colocar um Campo de pesquisa dentro do cabeçalho de um grid que mostra informações do banco de dados, para o usuário, a ideia é que tenha um campo pra cada coluna, possibilitando que o usuário filtre dentro do grid, somente escrevendo oq esta procurando. Tirei a ideia de um sistema aleatório que usamos na empresa que trabalho, parece ser feito em java, mais gostaria de fazer algo parecido em python usando a biblioteca PyQt5.

Segue exemplo caso não tenha ficado claro.[image: Exemplo]